# How does moving or switching between windows or frames work in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am writing a webscraping script that automatically logs into my Email account and sends a message.

I have written the code to the point where the browser clicks the "new Message" button. After that a new window (or frame?) opens where I can type in recipient address, subject and message.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

myPassword = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

browser = webdriver.Firefox() # Opens Firefox webbrowser
browser.get('https://protonmail.com/') # Go to protonmail website
loginButton = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.btn-ghost:nth-child(1)")))
loginButton.click()
usernameElem = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#username")))
usernameElem.send_keys("first.last@protonmail.com")
passwordElem = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("#password")
passwordElem.send_keys(myPassword)
anmeldenButton = browser.find_element_by_css_selector(".button")
anmeldenButton.click()
newMessage = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/button")))
newMessage.click()
addressElem = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#to-composer-1591")))
addressElem.send_keys('first.last@mail.com')
```

At the first of the following lines I get a TimeoutException error:

```
addressElem = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#to-composer-1591")))
addressElem.send_keys('asdf')
```

I think the error occurs, because the browser does not know where to find the element, correct?

I checked the documentation: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/navigating.html?highlight=frame#moving-between-windows-and-frames

The source code of the "new Message" button looks like that:

```
<button class="button button-large button-solid-norm text-bold mt0-25 w100 no-mobile" aria-busy="false" type="button" data-testid="sidebar:compose" aria-describedby="tooltip-8">Neue Nachricht</button>
```

[image]

The source code of the new window or frame:

```
<span class="flex-item-fluid p0-5 pr1 pl0-75 text-ellipsis user-select-none cursor-move">Neue Nachricht</span>
```

[image]

I am not sure if I am on the right way to solve the problem. I am trying to find information in the source code, that helps the browser to find the correct element and make use of the .switch_to_window() or .switch_to_frame() methods. First, I am not sure, if it is really a problem of switching to a new window or frame (I don't really know the difference between them). Second: how can I achieve to switch to the new element so that the browser can apply the .send_keys() method?

Comment: Hope this helps =>  this is because your driver does not switch to the new window. you may refer this => https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-switch-to-new-window-in-selenium-for-python/

Comment: I suggest you read about this => driver.window_handles

Comment: Please share your code trials. If possibly including the link to the page you are working on

Comment: Ok, I have now shared my code in the OP.

Comment: When you click on `new Message` button what happens? If it is a new window, you would see a new browser instance through your naked eyes but if it's an iframe you need to look into HTMLDOM to see if the frame exists or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked into the `HTMLDOM` and could not see any iframe or windows getting opened.

The reason why you are not able to interact with to input field is cause you are using this CSS selector `#to-composer-1591` the last part 1591 is dynamic in nature, what it means is that it will change on every new browser instance.

**Fix:**
You should use `input[id^='to-composer']` which is unique in entire HTMLDOM.

```
addressElem = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[id^='to-composer']")))
addressElem.send_keys('first.last@mail.com')
```